# How to update a resource using AngulaJS Rails Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-rails

I'm using [AngularJS Rails Resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource) and have it configured like so:

```
angular.module('admin')
.factory('Page', ['railsResourceFactory', 'API_PROVIDER', function(railsResourceFactory, API_PROVIDER) {
  return railsResourceFactory({
    url: API_PROVIDER.full_path + 'pages', //which resolves to https://example/api/pages
    name: 'page'
  });
}]);
```

And in my controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('admin')
    .controller('PagesEditController', PagesEditController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function PagesEditController($timeout, webDevTec, toastr, $scope, $moment, Page, Session, $http, $location, $anchorScroll, $stateParams) {

    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Token token='+ Session.token;

    var page = Page.get($stateParams.pageId).then(function (result) {
      $scope.editPage = result;
    });

    $scope.savePage = function (page) {
      page.update();
    }

  }
})();
```

In my view I have:

```
...
<input type="text" ng-model='editPage.title' class="form-control underline-input">
<button ng-click='savePage(editPage)' class="btn btn-green btn-ef btn-ef-7 btn-ef-7h" activate-button="success"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Save page</button>
...
```

**EDIT: My save function:**

```
$scope.savePage = function (page) {
  Page.get($stateParams.pageId).then(function (result) {
    result.title = $scope.editPage.title;
    result.content = $scope.editPage.content;
    result.update();
  })
}
```

But its not working. I get an error like so: `No route matches [PUT] "/api/pages"` which means the `PUT` request is not passing the object id when submitting the request.

I'm using Mongoid btw.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think it's connected with routing, not form. Have you tried restarting server? (that bumps routes). if it doesn't work please put your form code

Comment: Yes, I did restart the server and didn't work. I don't think the problem is on rails side as I can see the request being sent without the object id. I'm not using a form per se. All I have are the `input` with `ng-model` and a `ng-click` function `savePage(editPage)`.

Comment: Try to define `page` variable inside `$scope.savePage` function.

Comment: I've defined the `page` var inside the save function as you suggested but it didn't seen to help.